# What to use: wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) or DOING_AUTOSAVE?

Tags: posts, save-post

I was doing some action on `save_post` hook, and noticed that there exists

```
wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id )
```

function.

How does it differ from `DOING_AUTOSAVE` constant?

If I want my action not to run on autosave should I do both

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return;
}
```

and

```
if ( \wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {
  return;
}
```

Or is one enough?

The `DOING_AUTOSAVE` constant gets defined in `wp-admin/includes/post.php`, `wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php` and `wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-autosaves-controller.php`, whereas [`wp_is_post_autosave()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_post_autosave/) checks if the post is revision and has `autosave` in it's name.

I'm a bit confused what to use, and if it's good idea to use both.

Comment: If you want to check if a post is an auto-save, you should use the function; but if you want to check if WordPress *is doing* an auto-save, then you would check the constant.

Comment: But if WordPress is doing an autosave, the post type of that post would be auto save (or revision), no? Is it wrong to use both?

Comment: No, it's not wrong to use both. But normally, checking just the constant would do it in your case - i.e. if the constant is defined and a `true`, you can "exit" your callback function (cancel its action). If you only want to cancel your callback action if the post *has been successfully auto-saved*, then you would use the function.

Comment: No problem. And sorry, I didn't have a chance to correct the "the function" which should be "the function *as well*" - [example](https://pastebin.com/HbScaSmc).